# How to create a json 'POST' request in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I'm making a contact list app for a project to learn programming, and am currently creating the method to add a contact to a database through a Rest API I created.

The code below is for the `Add Contact` view, and I followed some tutorials on how to take data from a form, convert it to JSON and send it to a database via a POST request.

This is the code I've gotten, and what should be happening is that I should see a print of `responseJSON`, but that isn't happening, in fact nothing is happening and when I run the `checkDetails` function by pressing the button on the view I get the prints of `body` and `jsonData`, but nothing else. Not even an error.

I am a bit stumped here as I haven't changed much, if anything, from the tutorials I followed, so I am guessing it is something to do with my own code.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct AddContact: View {
    @State var id = 999
    
    @State var first_name: String = ""
    @State var last_name: String = ""
    @State var phone_number: String = ""
    @State var address: String = ""
    
    @State var birthday = Date()
    @State var birthdayString: String = ""
    @State var create_date = Date()
    @State var create_dateString: String = ""
    @State var updated_date = Date()
    @State var updated_dateString: String = ""

    @State var manager = DataPost()
    
    var body: some View {
        if manager.formCompleted {
            Text("Done").font(.headline)
        }
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section() {
                        TextField("First Name", text: $first_name)
                        TextField("Last Name", text: $last_name)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        TextField("Phone Number", text: $phone_number)
                        TextField("Address", text: $address)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        DatePicker("Birthday", selection: $birthday, displayedComponents: .date)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        Button(action: {
                            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
                            
                            birthdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: birthday)
                            create_dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: create_date)
                            updated_dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: updated_date)
                            
                            print("Clicked")
                            
                            self.manager.checkDetails(id: self.id, first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, phone_number: self.phone_number, address: self.address, birthday: self.birthdayString, create_date: self.create_dateString, updated_date: self.updated_dateString)
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Add Contact")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        })
                    }.disabled(first_name.isEmpty || last_name.isEmpty || phone_number.isEmpty || address.isEmpty)
                }
            }.navigationTitle("New Contact")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

class DataPost: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<DataPost, Never>()
    var formCompleted = false {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    func checkDetails(id: Int, first_name: String, last_name: String, phone_number: String, address: String, birthday: String, create_date: String, updated_date: String) {
        
        let body: [String: Any] = ["data": ["id": id, "first_name": first_name, "last_name": last_name, "birthday": birthday, "phone_number": phone_number, "create_date": create_date, "updated_date": updated_date, "address": address]]
                
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
                
        let url = URL(string: "https://flaskcontact-list-app.herokuapp.com/contacts")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        print(body)
        print(jsonData)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }

            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print(responseJSON)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use @StateObject for the ObservableObject vs State

Comment: @loremipsum You mean change `@State var manager = DataPost()` to `@StateObject var manager = DataPost()`? That didn't work, same issue.

Comment: Yes, and remove the didChange code and use @Published instead.

Comment: This is the line creating an issue because it return `nil` => `let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])`

Comment: So when you're trying to cast your `responseJSON` , the casting fails so `print(responseJSON)` will not be printed
            }`

Comment: The issue is the server you're hitting which is giving a Status Code of `404` so, it might not exist anymore

Comment: @loremipsum Where do I put the @Published? Sorry if it's an easy question.

Comment: @cedricbahirwe is correct. Your code works, it's just that the server is not responding. I tried to POST to this address: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", and that works.

Comment: @cedricbahirwe I checked the server logs, you're right it gives a `404`, yet when I use Postman to send a POST request, it works fine...

Comment: @workingdog Tried what you said, get the error "unsupported URL", but that's further than it got with my URL. However POST requests with my URL work fine when I use Postman, so could it still be something code related?

Comment: very strange, all I did was change the address, and it worked. What system are you on? Are you trying to do this in Preview?

Comment: `@Published var formCompleted = false`

Comment: @workingdog Xcode 12.5, macOS 11.4, using the Simulator. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I have other views for the list of contacts and detailed view, though that shouldn't affect it... Thats the only difference I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is the test code I use. Although I am on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst.
Tested on iPhone ios15 and macos 12. It "should be the same" on xcode 12.5 and macos 11.4.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@main
struct TestApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct AddContact: View {
    @State var id = 999
    
    @State var first_name: String = ""
    @State var last_name: String = ""
    @State var phone_number: String = ""
    @State var address: String = ""
    
    @State var birthday = Date()
    @State var birthdayString: String = ""
    @State var create_date = Date()
    @State var create_dateString: String = ""
    @State var updated_date = Date()
    @State var updated_dateString: String = ""
    
    @State var manager = DataPost()
    
    var body: some View {
        if manager.formCompleted {
            Text("Done").font(.headline)
        }
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section() {
                        TextField("First Name", text: $first_name)
                        TextField("Last Name", text: $last_name)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        TextField("Phone Number", text: $phone_number)
                        TextField("Address", text: $address)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        DatePicker("Birthday", selection: $birthday, displayedComponents: .date)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        Button(action: {
                            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
                            
                            birthdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: birthday)
                            create_dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: create_date)
                            updated_dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: updated_date)
                            
                            print("Clicked")
                            
                            self.manager.checkDetails(id: self.id, first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, phone_number: self.phone_number, address: self.address, birthday: self.birthdayString, create_date: self.create_dateString, updated_date: self.updated_dateString)
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Add Contact")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        })
                    }.disabled(first_name.isEmpty || last_name.isEmpty || phone_number.isEmpty || address.isEmpty)
                }
            }.navigationTitle("New Contact")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

class DataPost: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<DataPost, Never>()
    var formCompleted = false {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    func checkDetails(id: Int, first_name: String, last_name: String, phone_number: String, address: String, birthday: String, create_date: String, updated_date: String) {
        
        let body: [String: Any] = ["data": ["id": id, "first_name": first_name, "last_name": last_name, "birthday": birthday, "phone_number": phone_number, "create_date": create_date, "updated_date": updated_date, "address": address]]
        
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
        
        //  "https://flaskcontact-list-app.herokuapp.com/contacts"
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            print("-----> data: \(data)")
            print("-----> error: \(error)")
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }

            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print("-----1> responseJSON: \(responseJSON)")
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print("-----2> responseJSON: \(responseJSON)")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AddContact()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works for me, and when I use my URL I get nil. As I said before, a POST request works fine through Postman, therefore could the `404` error from the server be something related to the app?

Comment: Some progress I guess. 
It's not clear where the blockage is. You cannot make "my" url work in your app, 
although it works in the test code.
Also no one else can connect to your url.

Comment: And one more thing, why is there an `id` value of 101 outside of `data` in the `jsonResponse`?

Comment: Ahhhh I'm stupid, I didn't add https:// in the url! It works fine on my code.

Comment: great, the code you showed us is not the code you are using. 
Now you can start implementing all the good things @lorem ipsum 
has been telling you to do.